# Programmatically reading a dynamically created RSS feed using Java

Tags: java, rss, playframework-1.x

Our software is written using the Play! framework (Version 1.2.5) and we need to read RSS feeds. Up to now this has not been a problem, but we recently came across an RSS feed that is dynamically created using javascript in the onload event.

The code we currently use is as follows:

```
URL url = new URL(this.url);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36");     
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");   
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");            
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
String line;

while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
{
    result += line;
}
```

However, this is insufficient in the case of dynamically created RSS as all we get is a HTML page stating that javascript must be turned on.

I'm thinking we need some sort of embedded webpage, but that just seems like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Are there alternatives?

EDIT: After turning off javascript when browsing the RSS feed still returned the feed data in XML format, so that has compounded my confusion somewhat. It has been suggested that some RSS feeds use javascript to translate their feed using an XSLT, but the response I get from the request is:

"This site requires JavaScript and Cookies to be enabled. Please change your browser settings or upgrade your browser." So I'm not quite sure why this is occurring

Answer (score 0):

To scrape Javascript generated content I think you would have to use a Javascript engine to render the HTML contents.

You could use use something like [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) which is a light-weight pure Java headless browser. The only problem with HTMLUnit is that it uses a relatively old JavaScript engine.

In the past I have used [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) with [Selenium WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) to scrape JavaScript generated web pages.